# Re-entering the Schengen area for study after depleting 90/180

Tags: schengen

I am currently in Schengen on a C study visa. I will leave the Schengen area on May 1, after having spent 89 days.

However, there is a two-month summer school in the Schengen area in June that I want to attend. Is there any kind of visa I can apply for to do this?

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking but I assume this is not all happening in Schengen (the Luxembourgish village)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your only hope is to apply for a national "D" visa from the country where the summer school is located.  Mention in your application that you aren't eligible to attend on a C visa because of the 90/180 rule.

The problem may be that the program may be unable to sponsor its students for a national D student visa, whether because of the brief nature of the program or for some other reason.  If that is true, you may be out of luck.  There may be an administrator at the summer program who can tell you whether this is the case.

If your current program is in the same country where the summer program is located, there is a chance that you may be able to extend your stay. To do this, you would apply to the office responsible for issuing residence permits in that country.  Thanks to MertKarakaya for mentioning this in a comment.

Comment: For stays over 90 days, you either have to obtain a residency permit from the City Offices or have a long term stay visa "D" like phoog mentioned. As you are already out of the country/region, you can not apply for such permit, thus you would need to get the visa.

Comment: @MertKarakaya actually I think the asker is still in the Schengen area ("I am currently in Schengen...") so your point is well taken. Whether it's possible to apply to extend one's stay varies, however. Many countries allow only nationals of certain countries to do this. Also, the place for the application may or may not be "city offices," depending on the country. In some countries, such matters are handled by an office of the national government, for example.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I was talking from the "German" perspective. I know for Spain, residency permits are much harder to obtain. Even for the US citizen, they require an extensive background check.